# improving performance of iteration over a very large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, list-comprehension

I have a pandas dataframe which consists of 3 million rows and 50 columns which all contain integers (either positive or negative). I want to create a new column called 'feature' which takes the biggest negative number from the 50 existing columns.

For example, if for a given row the 50 columns contain the values

`-25,-24,-23,...,-1,1,...,23,24,25`

The 'feature' column should return -1.

Because my dataframe is so large the solutions I've tried are taking too long. For example, I've tried using list comprehensions but because I'm resorting to iterrows() it's too slow (itertuples() does not perform signficantly better):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

df = pd.read_csv('name_of_file.csv')

for idx, row in tqdm(df[list(np.arange(0,50,1))].iterrows()):
    df.loc[idx, 'feature'] = max([n for n in row if n < 0])
```

What is the fastest way to calculate this feature for such a large dataframe without having to resort to threading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use `DataFrame.where` to set all values above `0` to `NaN` and return the rowwise `max`:

```
df['feature'] = df.iloc[:,:50].where(df.iloc[:,:50].lt(0)).max(1)
```

Comment: I think you've got your slice mixed up, should be `[:,:50]`

Comment: True thanks @IanS don't know why I had rows in mind, updated!